# How can I set the iframe src to an IP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, embed

How can I set the src element of an iframe to an IP through Jquery?

```
<iframe src="page.html" id="iframe">
```

That's my HTML. When I try to edit the src via. Jquery, it doesn't work. All I get is a blank white screen

```
$('#iframe').attr('src','1.1.1.10');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the **scheme**, or two slashes, like so:

```
$('#iframe').attr('src','//1.1.1.10');
```

The **scheme** is HTTP or HTTPS.  Using // means the iframe will use the scheme of the page it is embedded in.

Comment: Great that fixed it. Thanks